# MYSQL:Compare column of 1 table with column of another table

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table `DATA`,

```
ID,CLASS,CODE,DATE
1,123456,10,12-10-2017
2,987654,40,2017-11-10
3,456789,50,2017-11-11
4,234567,60,2017-11-12
5,872341,150,2017-11-13
```

and another table `PROPS`,

```
ID,CLASS_ID,R_CODE
1,123456,20
2,987654,40
3,456789,50
4,234567,60
5,872341,100
6,746365,738
7,84264,8937
```

I would like to select all rows from `DATA` where `CODE` from `DATA` Table is greater than or equal to(`>=`) `R_CODE` from `PROPS` Table.

**Basically, i want to check each element of column `CODE` with every element of column `R_CODE` one-by-one.**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM data a, props b
WHERE a.code >= b.r_code
```

I am assuming class and class_id do not need to match?

Edit: The example is cross join wherein every row of the first table is matched with every row of the second table.  The where then filters to what you want.

Comment: Hi, i'm slightly new to sql. I just want to clear a doubt. I want to compare each element of `a.code` with all elements of `b.r_code` sequentially. Eg:. compare `20` of `a.code` with `20` then `40` then `50` then `60` ... upto `8937` of `b.r_code` respectively. Would your query do that?

Comment: Yes.  You can remove the WHERE clause to see the results prior to filtering.  What you see is a.row_1 joined with b.row_1, then a.row_1 with b.row_2, etc.  Once all of a.row_1 is matched with all b you a cross join then goes to a.row_2 with b.row_1, a.row_2 with b.row_2, etc.  If DATA has 1000 row and PROPS has 2000 rows then prior to filtering you will have 1000 * 2000 = 2,000,000 rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanations